# Craft 3 devMode doesn't turn off

Tags: craft3, devmode

I've been working on a site locally in `devMode`. I moved it from Craft 2 to Craft 3. I set `devMode` to `false` in `config/general.php` file and in admin it doesn't show the `devMode` bar at the top, but everything in the front of the site was pointing to my local environment.

The only thing that has worked is setting my siteUrl in the 'dev' to the actual site

```
// Dev environment settings
'dev' => [
    // Base site URL
    'siteUrl' => 'https://footwearoutfitters.net',

    // Dev Mode (see https://craftcms.com/support/dev-mode)
    'devMode' => false,
]
```

While this works, I'm concerned if it thinks it's running in `devMode` I'll have potential security threats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed this in the .env file, I'll leave this here in case anyone else is as bad a space case as myself. :)

```
# The environment Craft is currently running in ('dev', 'staging', 'production', etc.)
ENVIRONMENT="dev"
```

Comment: Just as a sanity check -- .make sure that `.env` is not checked into git